# Página personalizada para cada termo

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu tenho uma taxonomia chamada `Staff` e um termo chamado `Professores`, eu criei a página `taxonomy-staff.php` para exibir todos os professores contidos na taxonomia `staff` e `taxonomy-staff-professor.php` para exibir os professores cadastrados com o termo professor, porém não está exibindo a página, ele até obedece a rota e muda o título da página, mas o conteúdo não aparece. Alguém pode me ajudar?

segue o link do `taxonomy-stafftax-professor.php`

https://jsfiddle.net/uxyaumj4/

```
<?php
  get_header();
  get_template_part( 'wp-files/partials/banner' );
?>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Perfis dos professores</h3>
  <?php
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_type' => 'staff',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'stafftax',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => 'professor',
          )
        )
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'stafftax');
  ?>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<?php
  endwhile;
  endif;
  wp_reset_query();
?>


<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: Inclua o seu codigo, o erro provavelmente esta nele ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está reescrevendo a query, por isso pode estar tendo problemas.

Tente assim:
Arquivo `taxonomy-stafftax-professor.php`

```
<?php
  get_header();
  get_template_part( 'wp-files/partials/banner' );
?>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Perfis dos professores</h3>
  <ul>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
      </a>
    </li>
<?php
  endwhile;
  endif;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
  </ul>    

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: Eu consegui, na verdade, eu só precisava criar o single-{taxonomy}.php